# VSCode: How to see blocks with a list of branches, stashes, etc. again?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

With one of the latest updates to the VSСode, the expandable blocks with the list of branches, stesh, local history, etc. disappeared in the version control panel.
And if you right-click on the modified files, there is no stash changes option.

Questions:

1. How to see blocks with a list of branches, stashes, etc. again.
2. How to return to the context menu of the modified files the item for working with git stash?

[image]

**UPD 21.08.22: the problem was in GitLens, which I removed. Reinstalling GitLens brought back all the items I needed.**

Comment: Do you have the `GitLens` extension installed/enabled?

Comment: Indeed, the problem was in GitLens, which I removed. Reinstalling GitLance brought back all the items I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was in GitLens, which I removed. Reinstalling GitLance brought back all the items I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Go to vs code extensions, install the gitLens extension pack.
[gitLens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIUyO.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33258129)

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of vscode does not hide this. If you want to bring it back, you just need to `Right Click` on `SOURCE CONTROL` bar then pick the feature you want to display.

[image]